# Create macro to count specific words in column and insert total in another cell

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I am trying to create a formula(s) or macro that would help me do the following:

1. Count how many times a country name appears in a specific column
2. Then add the total of how many times it appeared in that specific column
3. Finally insert the total of the previous step into the neighboring column/row

Below I have inserted 2 pictures.

The 2nd picture will show a snippet of the spreadsheet with the countries.
The 1st shows a snippet of a table with the country and total users I would like to insert the totals. The table is next to the country column.

Please assist since I am having to do this for 64 countries with over 25,000 rows.

[image]

[image]

UPDATE!!!!

below are the results from your recommendation of how to setup the formula. Doesn't seem to be working. I tried to add the cell numbers next to column letter but still no dice.

Both pictures are shown below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2TIq.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxblT.png)

Comment: It sounds like you are just looking for the `CountIf` function?  Something like `=COUNTIF(N:N,O2)` copied down?

Comment: Hello - Demetri and - pnuts. I know how to use the countif function, but only familiar with writing a formula that would give a total for the a country in the cell where I am writing the formula.

Comment: Hello - Demetri and - pnuts. I know how to use the countif function, but only familiar with writing a formula that would give a total for the country in the cell where I am writing the formula. Example: In picture two I would write the formula in cell P2 (=countif(sheet1!N2:N25000). That isn't what I want, since I would have to edit the formula 64 times for each country. What I want is a formula, or macro give me a total for all 64 countries and insert the total on the cell(s) related to each country.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately my reputation isn't high enough to embed the images in this post, so I regretfully provided the links to the images instead. Apologies for this temporary inconvenience.

The comment by Demetri is correct on how to do this with a function. You won't have to edit the formula 64 times. I'll explain it with pictures (keep in mind my table data is different because I do not have the full table) .

1. The formula Demetri provided is shown in the formula bar, and as you can see it returns the number of times 'Cyprus' appears in column N. The O2 portion of the formula is referencing the country you are counting in column O.
2. See the small black square that appears when the cell P2 is selected (as indicated by the red box)? If you click and drag this, it will carry your formula down the column.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzIEs.png

3. The formula has been edited automatically by Excel down the column to take the country directly to the left of the "Total Good Users" column and search for the number of times it occurs in column N. If you select P4 as shown in the picture, the O2 has been changed to O4 (as highlighted by the red box).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyPTh.png

Simply drag this formula all the way down until the last country and it'll edit the formula for each country automatically.

Comment: Danno161 and Demetri. Thanks for update! :) I found that I had pasted the wrong column. When I tried to use it on the correct column, the formula didn't work. I have edited and added the correct picture. I want to compare column I and N and write the formula in column O and have the results in that column. I am trying to find the same thing that I stated originally on this post, but the extra commas and abbreviated cities next to the country are not giving me any results on the previous formula you were so kind to assist me. Please assist and again, thanks!

Comment: Simply change your formula to '=COUNTIF(N:N, "*" & O2 & "*")' for the locationname column. Putting the asterisk in quotations before and after the cell address allows you to find cells that contain what you are searching for, rather than requiring an exact match. 

By not giving specific information on what "Total Number of Good Users" implies in column O, it is difficult to tell what you are trying to do with it. Does compare mean add them together? Subtract one from the other? You need to be more specific.

Comment: =COUNTIF(N:N, '' * '' & O2 & '' * '') is the correct formula (no spacing between the quotation marks and asterisk), the previous comment interpreted it as formatting

If you are trying to add or subtract results within a cell, simply add another COUNTIF statement after the first. =COUNTIF(N:N, '' * '' & O2 & '' * '') + COUNTIF...

Comment: @Danno161...I tried your recommendation and it returned a value of 0. I added the cell numbers next to the column letter and still wouldn't work. What could be the problem??? :(